# Lightning: Need help understanding @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, documentation, aura-enabled, cacheable

Going through the [Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_auraenabled_annotation.htm) I found this statement.

> To set cacheable=true, a method must only get data. It can’t mutate data.

Does data mutation only refer to DML operations?

I have a method to retrieve multiple records but I need to return them as a list of Wrapper objects. So I am running the retrieved records through a FOR loop. Would this be considered as *altering* the data? Would the method not cache the results on the client in this case?

If so, is there another approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restriction is only about making permanent database changes, such as a DML statement, calling a future method, etc. Modifying data in memory is allowed.